# preg_replace - which of these words are causing problems?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to do a "find and replace" of glossary terms on my website.

The terms are taken from my database and built like this from a simple array of strings:

```
/* get the glossary terms */
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT post_title AS list FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="glossary" AND post_parent>0' );

$glossary_terms = array();

foreach ( $results as $row ) {
    $term = preg_quote( str_replace( array("/", "'"), array("&#47;", "&quot;"), $row->list ) );
    $glossary_terms[] = $term;
}
```

This `$glossary_terms` is used as `$glossary` in the function below:

```
$urls    = array();
$pattern = array();

// build a normalized lookup (case-insensitive, whitespace-agnostic)
foreach ($glossary as $term) {
    $term_norm = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strtoupper(trim($term)));
    $pattern[] = preg_replace('/ /', '\\s+', preg_quote($term_norm));
    $initial = substr($term, 0, 1);
    $urls[$term_norm] = '/dev/glossary/' . $initial . '/' . rawurlencode($term);
    $rels[$term_norm] = '/dev/glossary/' . $initial . '/' . rawurlencode($term) . '?preview=true';
    $title[$term_norm] = $term;
}

$pattern  = '/\b(' . implode('|', $pattern) . ')\b/i';
```

Now, `$pattern` is displaying [this list of words](http://pastebin.com/1n21kzte). An excerpt of that, including a few words which I think may be causing me problems, is:

> MANGROVE\s+TREE|MANTLE|MARACYN|MARACYN\-2|MARBLED|MARGIN|MARGINAL|MARINE|MATROTROPHY|MATURE|MAXILLA|MAXILLARY|MEANDER|MEDIAL|MEDIAN|MELANIN|MELANOPHORE|MEMBRANE|MENISCUS|MENTAL|MENTAL\s+BARBEL|MERISTIC|MERISTICS|MERISTIC\s+CHARACTER|MESETHMOID|MESIAL|MESO\-|MESOCORACOID|META\-|METABOLISM|METAMORPHOSIS|METRONIDAZOLE|METHYLENE\s+BLUE|MICROORGANISM|MICROPREDATOR|MICROPYLE|MICROSATELLITE|MIGRATE|MIGRATION|MILLILITRE\s+\(ML\)|MICRO\s+CRAB|MICROLITRE|MICROWORM|MILT|MIMESIS|MIMETIC|MIMIC|MIMICRY|ML|MODAL|MODE|MOLLUSC|MOLLUSCA|MONO\-|MONOECIOUS|MONOGAMOUS|MONOGAMY|MONOPHYLETIC|MONOSPECIFIC|MONOTYPIC|MORPHOLOGY|MORPHOMETRICS|MORPHOMETRIC\s+CHARACTER|MORPHOMETRY|MOTTLED|MOUTH\-BROODER|MOUTH\s+ROT|

The problem I'm having is that the filter is going haywire, linking every single space and word in the `$content`.

**My question is** which terms from `$pattern` (as per pastebin/excerpt) are causing this problem? I suspect it's something to do with `'` as in `BAUDELOT'S\s+LIGAMENT` but I'm not sure how to correct this, as `preg_quote` doesn't seem to escape apostrophes?

---

**EDIT** here's the additional code, to try and determine if this is the problem rather than the `preg_replace`:

```
$text_nodes = $xpath->query('//text()[not(ancestor::a)]');

foreach($text_nodes as $original_node) {
    $text     = $original_node->nodeValue;
    $hitcount = preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if ($hitcount == 0) continue;

    $offset   = 0;
    $parent   = $original_node->parentNode;
    $refnode  = $original_node->nextSibling;

    $parent->removeChild($original_node);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $match) {
        $term_txt = $match[0];
        $term_pos = $match[1];
        $term_norm = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strtoupper($term_txt));

        // insert any text before the term instance
        $prefix = substr($text, $offset, $term_pos - $offset);
        $parent->insertBefore($document->createTextNode($prefix), $refnode);

        // insert the actual term instance as a link
        $link = $document->createElement("a", $term_txt);
        $link->setAttribute("href", $urls[$term_norm]);
        $link->setAttribute("rel", $rels[$term_norm]);
        $link->setAttribute("class", "link_glossary");
        $parent->insertBefore($link, $refnode);

        $offset = $term_pos + strlen($term_txt);

        if ($i == $hitcount - 1) {  // last match, append remaining text
            $suffix = substr($text, $offset);
            $parent->insertBefore($document->createTextNode($suffix), $refnode);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm not sure how to correct this, as preg_quote doesn't seem to escape apostrophes?

`preg_quote` doesn't need to escape apostrophes, because they are not special within a regex.

I don't see why this regex should match every single space and all not listed words.

But a problem I see is, you surround the regex alternation with word boundaries `\b`, this will be problematic in the those cases where the words does note end with a word character, like "MACRO\-|" or "MESO\-|MESOCORACOID|META\-|". Of course it will match if there is directly a word character after the dash. (I don't know the text you want to match.)

Comment: So stema, do you think that this `$pattern` is OK, and that it should match correctly? What about the sections like `WORMS\s+\\\(PARASITE\\\)` - what exactly is that matching? Excuse my ignorance, I'm very bad at regex.

Comment: `\s+` is matching one ore more whitespace characters, here most likely spaces or tabs. Brackets are special characters in regex, that need escaping when they should be matched literally. I am not sure, why there are 3 backslashes, but I assume your example would match a string like "WORMS (Parasite)".

Comment: I've added the extra code to the OP. Without analysing exactly what the problem might be, would your best guess be that the code which runs the filter itself is the cause of the problem rather than the `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 0):

`$term_norm = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strtoupper(trim($term)));`

You need to `preg_quote($term)` there ^

Comment: The `$term` is `preg_quote'd` earlier on - in the first foreach loop. Doesn't that satisfy the requirement?